# Does anyone know the exit codes for tfsbuild.exe?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Does anyone know the exit codes for [tfsbuild.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb558974%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)?

I have looked on MSDN, but I cannot find any information.

Answer (score 7):

There is no documentation in MSDN

So I had to decompile TFSBuild.exe (thankfully it is .NET)

So exit codes I found there are

- Unknown = -1,
- Success = 0,
- PartialSuccess = 1,
- UnrecognizedCommand = 2,
- NotAttempted = 3,
- SuccessRebootRequired = 4,
- Failure = 100

This is valid for version 11.0.0.0 of TFSBuild.exe
but i do not think they change them often